# Decorrelating the data

Tags: machine-learning, regression, linear-regression, eigenvector, eigenvalue

How can we calculate square root of a non-square matrix? 
p.s. I tried Jordan Matrix Decomposition method but it seems it's applicable only on square matrices.

Comment: So many questions. Do you want suggestions how to process the sensor data? If so, show us how they look if you want useful suggestions how to process them. Or do you want a recipie for least-squares linear regression of some variable y (400 values)? IMO there is no point to decorrelate your 3 columns before that (allthough you might want to high-pass filter them, but it's hard to tell without seeing the data). Or are you asking for clarification about what you read in that paper? I have no idea which one you want answered, and it's near impossible to answer all at once. Sorry for the downvote.

Comment: Maxy,Thanks for your comment. After reading your comment, when i read my question again i also felt it was not clear. So, now i have rephrased my question. I hope it's clear this time.

Comment: Unfortunately, i cannot share the data as it belongs to a company and it's confidential.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to consider http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis

There are a lot of tutorials and howtos e.g. for matlab out there.
(Sometimes making your original data unit variance before is beneficial)

Comment: Thanks Benroth for the answer. I think earlier my question was not clear. Now, i have rephrased it. Actually, with the help of normalization technique, i achieved unit variance in my data. But my problem is i could not decorrelate it. I read somewhere, in order to decorrelate, we need to calculate Eigen Values and Eigen Vectors of the matrix. But in my case, the matrix is not a square matrix. So, how can i calculate Eigen Values and Eigen Vectors?

Comment: Usually, for de-correlating with PCA or similar methods, the eigenvectors are calculated from the covariance matrix (which is square) of the data matrix. Unfortunately your current phrasing of the question doesn't mention the actual ('primal') problem you want to solve anymore, so it's hard to give useful hints.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are dealing with a non-square matrix you should apply singular value decomposition. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition

By the way "the square root of a non-square matrix" is a concept that is not well defined. I guess you meant "a decomposition of a non-square matrix". There exist many decomposition types, but for general-purpose analyses the SVD is the most informative.